# Any possible way to access class with internal constructors outside of its assemby location? C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012

Hi as mentioned above.

Is there any way at all to get access to class with internal constructors and not change it to public at all?

Or is there nothing to do at all and just live with the fact that the class can only be used in that assemby file it exists in?

Comment: Is the class in your assembly?

Comment: You can via reflection? Is this a route you are willing to go down?

Comment: You can use reflection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[InternalsVisibleTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) exposes internally visible types to a specific assembly - I'd imagine that would work for you

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using reflection and Dynamic extensions

create instance

```
object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("DALL.LoadClass, DALL", true));

 dynamic dObject = obj;
 dObject.YourMethod();
```